# AppHostHttpListenerBase & Remote Connections

Tags: servicestack

I've setup a small ServiceStack using self-hosting via the AppHostHttpListenerBase class.  Instead of using localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the baseUri, I'm using the ip of the machine.  When connecting locally it works great, but when connecting from other devices (laptops, desktops, tablets, etc.) it just times out.

Here is my AppHost and how I launch it.

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    private static ILog log;

    public AppHost() : base("ServiceStack Examples", typeof(AppHost).Assembly)
    {
        LogManager.LogFactory = new DebugLogFactory();
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AppHost));
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
    }
}

string path = "http://192.168.3.125:8889/";
var appHost = new AppHost();
appHost.Init();
appHost.Start(path);
System.Console.WriteLine("AppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}", DateTime.Now, path);
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
System.Console.WriteLine("ReadLine()");
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

This is being developed in Xamarin compiled with .NET 4.0 using latest ServiceStack libs, etc.  Running on Windows 8 Pro and launch Xamarin with Administrator rights, etc.

Am I missing something?  I've looked all over but haven't seen anything that seems to point me in a specific direction.  Nor did I see any disclaimers at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting about not allowing remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a specific IP and Port, then it will only listen to incoming connections on that IP:port. i.e. it wont work if they connect to that machine using a different IP. You can use a wildcard to listen to all IPs on that machine, e.g:

```
appHost.Start("http://*:8889/");
```

Otherwise if that still doesn't work it's likely being blocked by a firewall.